# using screen command to run a multiprocessing python script hangs

Tags: command-line, ssh, python

Im trying to run a python script that uses multiprocessing since it's a long operation so i perform

```py
import multiprocessing
multiprocessing.pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
```

and since im running it over a server with SSH so im using the screen command to run it to avoid connection breaks.
the problem is if i try to run it normally without screen it runs ok but with screen it hangs for more than 10 mins and it doesnt start the processes.

is there a different command i can use for background process or a solution for screen with multiprocessing?

Answer (score 1):

the problem was the way i ran the script it had nothing to do with the screen command or multiprocessing. i wanted to have all the output in a text file so i used this

```bsh
python mpscript 2>&1 | tee sp1m-output.txt
```

apparently the piping didn't work properly and caused this.

Comment: In `bash` you can use the shorthand `|&` to pipe both stdout and stderr: `python script |& tee out.txt` See `man bash`/SHELL GRAMMAR/Pipelines.